# How to write a function in R to remove the row with NDs from a dataset

Tags: r, loops

I am doing a project in R, and I want to filter some useless data by using loops in order to create a new data set. This is what I have done now:

```
rate <- read.csv(file.choose())
attach(rate)
eur <- rate[, c("Series.Description", "SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE...EURO.AREA.")]
```

[image: eur]

For example, the 11th row has ND. I remove it and the 12th row will be the 11th row in the new data set. How can I do that?

Comment: the second column is going to be a character or factor and you probably want numeric. try `read.csv(file.choose(), na.strings = c('NA', 'ND'))` to compare

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!
You don't need a loop for that. Basic indexing or subsetting is enough. `R` is really powerful with this:

```
eur <- rate[rate[,2]!="ND",]
```

Also try avoid `attach()`, its use can cause problems if not handled properly. Try to look up how indexing and subsetting works in `R`. You can find a lot of good tutorials online. For example [here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/ItDT/HTML/node65.html) and [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).

**Note:** Make your questions and problems reproducible. Posting your code or data as an image is not useful in most cases. Try to use `dput(YOURDATA)` instead.

Comment: Thx! But what I want is not just remove the rows with ND. For example, the 11th row has ND. I remove it and the 12th row will be the 11th row in the new data set. How can do that?

Comment: @Victoria Chan In my understanding, this is exactely what the posted code does. Please correct me if I am wrong.